# DevOps Upgrade - UAT is not anchored

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Am having the issue below when running azure devops migration tool, any pointers on what is causing the issue?
Error:
[12:39:29 INF] Migrating all Nodes before the Processor run.
[12:39:30 INF]  Processing Node: \Streamlined\Area\ Inventory\ Management\MMS Upgrade UAT, start date: null, finish date: null
[12:39:30 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
System.InvalidOperationException: Path \Streamlined\Area\ Inventory\ Management\MMS Upgrade UAT is not anchored in the target project, it cannot be created.
at MigrationTools.Enrichers.TfsNodeStructure.GetOrCreateNode(String nodePath, Nullable`1 startDate, Nullable`1 finishDate) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\ProcessorEnrichers\TfsNodeStructure.cs:line 157

Comment: Please submit bug reports on the project's GitHub issues page. Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker for third-party tools.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem just today, and it was caused, for me, by a lowercase 't' that should have been uppercase in the project name. I'd suggest taking a closer look at your config to make sure that you haven't flipped case anywhere by accident.